# How to retrieve plain text from url in flutter?

Tags: http, flutter

I am trying to retrieve text from url from server.

the text is simple plain text present in html body tag.

random token value:

[image]

trying to retrieve in flutter

```
Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://localhost:8080/braintree/main.php"),

    );
    // data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    final String tokenID = await response.body.toString();
    String x="";
  }
```

Not working what is proper way to retrieve plain text from url.

Comment: not getting string token id from response body

Comment: getting body  = null

Comment: try https server.